# Adding a generator to the presentation of a group.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-presentation, quotient-group

I’m reading about Tietze transformation and want to check my understanding. Here’s the statement and an example.

> Given a presentation it is possible to add a new generator that is expressed as a word in the original generators. Starting with $G=\left\langle x \mid x^{3}=1\right\rangle$ and letting $y=x^{2}$ the new presentation $G=\left\langle x, y \mid x^{3}=1, y=x^{2}\right\rangle$ defines the same group.

Does this say that, since a word like $x^2y$ from the second presentation can be expressed as $x^2x^2 = x$, it is already included in the group defined by the first presentation? I’m trying to get a setup like that in the First Isomorphism Theorem, i.e. having free groups and homomorphisms $\phi_1: F_{\{x\}} \to G$ and $\phi_2: F_{\{x,y\}} \to G$. What would be ker $\phi_2$ in this case?

Also can we just let $y$ be an arbitrary word? For example, if given a group $G=\left\langle x \mid x^{5}=1\right\rangle$, can we have $y = x^2,x^3,x^4$?

Comment: Yes, $y$ can be an arbitrary word in the existing generators.

Comment: The group with the extra generator is not equal to the original group as your notation suggests, but isomorphic to it under a map with $x \mapsto x$ \and $y \mapsto x^2$. And yes, the new generator can be put equal to an arbitrary word in the original generators.